# NoReverseMatch error in django when added a form

Tags: python, django

I created an app called jobs in my django project. I included the **jobs** `urls.py` file to my main `urls.py` file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r'^jobs/', include('jobs.urls', namespace="jobs")),
]
```

In my **jobs** `urls.py` file I have a url.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^post/', views.post_view, name="post"),
]
```

Here is the view code for this url.

```
def post_view(request):
    form = forms.PostJobForm()
    return render(request, 'jobs/post_job_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the html for this form.

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Post a Job{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Post Job"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the actual form python code.

```
class PostJobForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Ever since I added these things to my project, nothing seems to work. Whenever I run the local development server and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/, which is the route url of the project or any other url for that matter, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /jobs/post/
Reverse for 'jobs.views.' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

It later says it is a template rendering error which occurs at line 0. What's going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: The code you provided looks fine to me, my guess would be that somewhere else in the code there is something like `reverse('jobs.views.)` or `{% url 'jobs.views.' %}` in templates.
Searching for `jobs.views.` in the whole repository should help.

Comment: Please show the `layout.html` template.

Comment: Thank you so much @pawel.ad. I was getting so frustrated.

Comment: @TomFinet glad I could help : )